# Detect if application was started as HTTP server or not (rake task, rconsole etc)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, eventmachine

I'm using [EventMachine](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine) and [Monetarily](https://github.com/eatenbyagrue/momentarily) to start e TCP server along with my rails application. This is started from `config/initializers/momentarily.rb`.

My problem is that it starts also when I run rake tasks, like `db:migrate`. I only want it to start when when I start the HTTP server. Environments won't help, since both the server start and rake tasks are under Development environment. Is there a way of knowing that the application is running the HTTP server as opposed to anything else? Note that is not only rake tasks, the EM starts also if I run the rails console, which is again something not desirable for my case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's not a great way of doing this that I know of. You could copy [newrelic](https://github.com/newrelic/rpm)'s approach (check `discover_dispatcher` in [local_environment.rb](https://github.com/newrelic/rpm/blob/master/lib/new_relic/local_environment.rb)) which basically has a list of heuristics used to detect if it is running inside passenger, thin, etc.

For passenger it checks

```
defined?(::PhusionPassenger)
```

for thin it checks

```
if defined?(::Thin) && defined?(::Thin::Server)
```

Comment: That's actually promising. Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me in Rails 4 with passenger.

Comment: The constant to check seems to be ::PhusionPassenger now

Comment: @DanHerman looks like either the constant to check changed or it was a typo all along

Answer (score 9):

```
unless File.basename($0) == "rake" && ARGV.include?("db:migrate")
  # you are not in rake db:migrate
end
```

Answer (score 7):

Set an environment variable in `config.ru` file, and use it anywhere in the code to detect if it's executed using a `rails server` command only.

For e.g.

- *File:* `config.ru`

  ```
  ENV['server_mode'] = '1'
  ```

And using it somewhere as:

- *File:* `config/environment.rb`

  ```
  Thread.new { infinite_loop! }.join if ENV['server_mode'] = '1'
  ```

---

Reference: [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17414005/1052356)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can implement a switch in the initializer based on `ARGV`?

Something like:

```
if ARGV.join(' ').match /something/
  # your initializer code here
end
```

Comment: it would have to work in production too, when running under Apache

Answer (score 0):

Don't start that other server from an initializer. Create a [daemon](http://daemons.rubyforge.org) in `script/momentarily` and start it from within your app.

Comment: I would still need to know when to start the daemon and when not

Answer (score 0):

After your application launches, you could have it shell out to check `ps`.  If `ps` shows that the HTTP server is running and the running HTTP server has the same pid as your application (check the pid by inspecting `$$`), then you could launch the TCP server.

Comment: Yes it will. When you run rails server `ps aux | grep rails` will contain something like `remus 18454   0.0  0.8  2515572  65968 s000  S+   11:10AM   0:01.51 /Users/remus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby script/rails server`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to a great answer by Frederick Cheung above, there can be some other "footprints" in actual process environment. Eg. Phusion Passenger adds certain variables to ENV such as:

```
PASSENGER_APP_ENV
IN_PASSENGER
PASSENGER_SPAWN_WORK_DIR
PASSENGER_USE_FEEDBACK_FD
```

Web servers typically can also set `SERVER_SOFTWARE` variable eg.:

```
SERVER_SOFTWARE=nginx/1.15.8 Phusion_Passenger/6.0.2
```